# Capture exception in Async.Start?

Tags: f#

I have the following code. And I want to run without blocking the main thread.

```
let post () = .....
try
    let response = post ()
    logger.Info(response.ToString())
with 
| ex -> logger.Error(ex, "Exception: " + ex.Message)
```

So I changed the code to the following. However, how to catch the exception in `post`?

```
let post = async { 
   ....
   return X }
try
    let response = post |> Async.StartChild
    logger.Info(response.ToString())
with 
| ex -> logger.Error(ex, "Exception: " + ex.Message)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd put the try/catch in an `async` block as well

```
let post = async { .... }
async {
  try
    let! response = post
    logger.Info(response.ToString())
  with 
  | ex -> logger.Error(ex, "Exception: " + ex.Message)
} |> Async.Start
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `Async.Catch` in a calling workflow. Given a couple of functions (a throwaway "async" function and something to work with the result):

```
let work a = async {
    return 
        match a with 
        | 1 -> "Success!"
        | _ -> failwith "Darnit"
}

let printResult (res:Choice<'a,System.Exception>) = 
    match res with
    | Choice1Of2 a -> printfn "%A" a
    | Choice2Of2 e -> printfn "Exception: %s" e.Message
```

`One can use Async.Catch`

```
let callingWorkflow = 
    async {
        let result = work 1 |> Async.Catch
        let result2 = work 0 |> Async.Catch

        [ result; result2 ]
        |> Async.Parallel
        |> Async.RunSynchronously
        |> Array.iter printResult
    }

callingWorkflow |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

`Async.Catch` returns a `Choice<'T1,'T2>`. `Choice1Of2` for a successful execution, and the exception thrown for the `Choice2Of2`.

Comment: How to pass `work` function to `printResult` for the first solution?